# Mule message Invocation scope property

Tags: mule

I have a MuleClient that sends a message to a Mule flow like below but I dont see properties reflected in the mule flow in response section, what scope should I make the properties to be?

```
MuleMessage msg = new DefaultMuleMessage();
Map<String,Object> propertiesMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
propertiesMap.put("name", "hello");
msg.addProperties( propertiesMap, PropertyScope.INVOCATION);
```

then in the flow I tried to access this property like this

```
message.getInvocationProperty("name")
```

and it returns null... What am i missing?

Comment: How do you send to the flow? It is not shown above.

Comment: i have tried this two ways...
   `code` client.send( "vm://myPath", msg);`code`
I have also tried this 
   `code` client.send("vm://myPath", payload, propertiesMap );

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you send a message to a flow using a VM (or any transport) endpoint, invocation properties will not be propagated.

You need to place the properties in the outbound scope: they will arrive in the inbound scope out of the inbound endpoint of the flow.

Comment: you mean like the Outbound Property sent through a VM Transport will be "changed" or received as an Inbound Property? Mule transform Outbound to Inbound automatically? Thanks.

Comment: It's not a matter of transformation but really a matter of where you are in the interaction: as the sender, the properties are in the outbound scope, which ends up in the inbound scope for the receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are sending the MuleMessage to Connector (ie. inbound vm ), Invocation properties not available in your flow. MessageProperties in outbound scope wil be modified into inbound scope. so use the outbound scope, in your flow access like #[message.inboundPrperties['name']]